# How to save data in c# for multiple condition

Tags: c#, if-statement

I have a problem i want to save some data in my Sql Server database using if condition :
if the enter some data into text-box then that will save(which i know)
but 
the problem is if the user didn't enter any data in Text-box then it save "0" by default

Answer (score 0):

try

```
string valueToBeSaved ="0";
try{
if(textField.getText()!=""||textField.getText()!=null){
valueToBeSaved = textField.getText();}
}catch(Exception ex){}

SaveToDatabase(valueToBeSaved);
```

textField -> the input field that contains the text you want to be saved
SaveToDatabase(string valueToBeSaved); -> your method where you save it to the database.

Note; you can omit the try catch and even the if statement by using single line values or by assigning default values in your method. However i didnt do this because i dont know what the rest of your code looks like.